# Python numpy convert 2d array in 1d array sorted

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array and I want to change this array into a 1D which is sorted. For example:

```
A = [[1,0,2],
     [0,3,0]]
```

I want this to be like:

```
B = [3,2,1,0,0,0]
```

Any idea how I can do this using python modules and not to write a sorting algorithm or anything like that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are looking to sort them in descending order -

```
In [127]: A
Out[127]: [[1, 0, 2], [0, 3, 0]]

In [128]: B = np.sort(np.array(A).ravel())

In [129]: B[::-1]
Out[129]: array([3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Basically, it involves three steps: Flatten the array with `ravel()`, sort it with `np.sort` and then reverse the indexing for an effect of `descending` order sorting.

Comment: @EdChum haha happens I guess! :)

Comment: @EdChum Ah that was okay! Well, I liked your one-liner though.

Answer (score 1):

## This is my solution:

```
A = [[1,0,2], [0,3,0]]
B = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[i])):
        B.append(A[i][j])

B.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=True)
print B
```

You can see my code running here: http://ideone.com/P8xBPK